# Query Select Sql with Condition from a Value of Html combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem of my web programming using php. I have an input form where there are two combobox with several options.
In the form, there also a textfield of *Code* where the value is determined by what is selected from both combobox (as the condition) from mySql database using select query.

Like= `Select code from tableA where condition1=itemComboA and condition2=itemComboB;`

I wanna ask, how to retrieve the value of the textfield automatically when user select an item in both combobox?

The query above still not working, then I manage it to select the *code* in another page then I redirect it to the input form by using link with the *Code* Like this: `http://localhost/data/input.php?code=6`

I still can't Set the value='`<?php echo $code ?>;`' in the value of textfield because the select query isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html will look like this

```
       <form action="input.php" action="GET">
            <select name="code">
                <option value="1"> option 1</option>
                <option value="2"> option 2</option>
                <option value="3"> option 3</option>
            </select>

            <select name="code2">
                <option value="drp1"> option 1</option>
                <option value="dpr2"> option 2</option>
                <option value="drp3"> option 3</option>
            </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

for testing purposes, in your php file, print this to show content of your array

```
print_r($_GET);
```

from there you can get the values to put into your mysql query

```
$query = 'SELECT code FROM tableA WHERE condition1 = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['code1']) . ' AND condition2 = ' mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['code2']) . ';';
```

Comment: How if I put the php code including the query in the same file with the html form?
Do I need to put print_r($_GET) in the textfield value?

Comment: you create a form with a submit button in your html file. when you click on "submit" your form will post to you php page (input.php). from there you use $_GET['code'] and $_GET['code2'] to put values into your MYSQL query

Comment: LOL they get the answer and run!

Comment: @user2035819 I got it, but still try to analyze and apply it on my code
Anyway, I'm thinking of using Ajax to solve it

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your php file you can have:

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST) {
        $query = 'SELECT code FROM tableA WHERE condition1 = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemComboA']) . ' AND condition2 = ' mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemComboB']) . ';';
    }

?>
```

It seems as though your form doesn't have `method="post"` defined so you may need use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`.